# When it comes to making shared object from assembly language source, what things different with from C source shoud I do?

Tags: linux, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

It's on ARM architecture, Raspberry Pi 3B. When I tried to use the same method with C to make a lib*.so from assembly language sources, a weird error occured. My *Makefile* looks like:

```
a.s: a.S
    cpp -o $@ $<

a.o: a.s
    as -o $@ $<

liba.so: a.o
    gcc -shared $^ -o $@

main: main.c liba.so
    gcc -L. $< -la -o $@

a_debug.o: a.s
    as -gstabs+ -o $@ $<

main_debug: main.c a_debug
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

*main_debug* could be made without problems; but when making *main*, linker reported an error:

> libfxp.so: undefined reference to `r2'

Why would it take the register mnemonic as a label?

Comment: need to show more.

Comment: @old_timer I've found the problem. Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

It's all because I misused the macro mechanism of the GNU assembler.
I defined a macro:

```
.macro neg64 reg0, reg1, insset
mvn \reg0, \reg0
mvn \reg1, \reg1
.if \insset == 32
    adds \reg0, \reg0, #1
    adc \reg1, #0
.else
    mov \insset, #1
    cmn \reg0, \insset
    adc \reg1, \reg1, \insset
    sub \reg1, \reg1, #1
    add \reg0, \reg0, #1
.endif
.endm
```

And called it:

```
neg64 r0, r1, r2
```

And then this error occured. In my imagination，this will work when calling 'neg64   32' at ARM mode and 'neg64   ' at Thumb mode but it's not true. Obiviously the assembly macro-extension works in a different way with C preprocessor which just does literal replacements. My solution is to discard this weird definition and write a 'neg64_arm' and 'neg64_thumb'. The exact answer needs more reference to GNU assembler manual.